# Change bluetooth MAC address in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth, mac-address

I know is it possible to change the bluetooth MAC address in Linux, but I need to do it for Windows.

Is there any way to do it using WINAPI?

Comment: There is a post [in MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4a687b9-08c3-4cee-8130-14bc375297a7/windows-7-embedded-setting-csr-bluetooth-mac-address-using-ioctlbthhcivendorcommand-fail-with?forum=wdk) from someone attempting the same.

Comment: There is a [list of all the bluetooth-related functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927(v=vs.85).aspx) in MSDN. If what you want is possible the function to do it should be there.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see anything related in functions list, but the first msdn post is good. I will try to join discussion there in hope to get the answer.

Comment: Just be warned, from what I gathered it might not be possible at all, or if it is, it could be a pretty difficult thing to do, and would involve hacks. I saw a post (can't find it so I can't post link) where a Microsoft developer said that getting the bluetooth MAC address is not possible through public APIs, and if getting it is not possible, then setting it's probably not, too.

Comment: @Kosmos can you share how to do the same in linux

Comment: http://blog.petrilopia.net/hacking/change-your-bluetooth-device-mac-address/ they use some "btaddr" for that, but I am not a Linux user and don't know much.

Comment: @sashoalm Thanks you, but I will hope it possible :O

Comment: I came across this https://macaddresschanger.com